# Is there a way to stop texture paint from "repainting areas"?

Tags: texture-painting

I paint an area of the model and then release the mouse button. Then I start paint some nearby area of the model again but unless I am pixel perfect careful, some areas of the model will become darker when painting close areas.

So unless I paint entire model areas at once, which is nearly impossible, I can't paint the model that easily.

Is there some way around this? Some setting that prevents "re-painting" areas of model that already have been painted?